# how do I change my skin on Minecraft Pocket Edition when there is no change skin button?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft Pocket Edition version is 0.15.2, when I go onto the place where you change your skin there is no change skin button on top of my character/person. Does anyone know how I can change my skin now?

Comment: Have you looked in all of the settings? They recently moved it.

Comment: i have checked my minecraft settings but there is nothing, do you know where they moved it to

Comment: It should be on the main menu, on the right of "Play" and "Achievements". Tap on the clothes hangar.

iOS v0.15.2. You may need to sign into a Microsoft account first for it to work properly.